# pretty-print json in python (pythonic way)

Tags: python, json

I know that the `pprint` python standard library is for pretty-printing python data types. However, I'm always retrieving json data, and I'm wondering if there is any easy and fast way to pretty-print json data?

No pretty-printing:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://server.com/api/2/....')
r.json()
```

With pretty-printing:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> r = requests.get('http://server.com/api/2/....')
>>> pprint(r.json())
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pprint`?

Comment: In your example you're not printing JSON anywhere. You decode it (by doing `r.json()`), so it's just a Python data structure after that. So what exactly do you want to pretty print? Python data structures or JSON?

Comment: mmm you're right. Both cases.

Answer (score 149):

Python's builtin [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) can handle that for you:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = {'hello': 'world', 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> print(json.dumps(a, indent=2))
{
  "hello": "world",
  "a": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: weird, getting `/` separated string in notebook output

Comment: The `indent=2` is what brought the magic to me. Tried without it first and got nothing but a wall of entries.

Answer (score 27):

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('http://server.com/api/2/....')
pretty_json = json.loads(r.text)
print (json.dumps(pretty_json, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 24):

I used following code to directly get a json output from my requests-get result and pretty printed this json object with help of pythons json libary function [.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) by using indent and sorting the object keys:

```py
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://example.org')
print (json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a blend of all answers and an utility function to not repeat yourself:

```
import requests
import json

def get_pretty_json_string(value_dict):
    return json.dumps(value_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)

# example of the use
response = requests.get('http://example.org/').json()
print (get_pretty_json_string (response))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use for show unicode values and key.

```
print (json.dumps(pretty_json, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

#This Should work

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://server.com/api/2/....')
formatted_string = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
print(formatted_string)
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your code.

Comment: There is a typo in your imports, always be sure to test your code before posting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

These answers are good if you want to print the entire json/dict. However, there are times when you only want the "outline", since the values are too long. In this case you can use this:

```
def print_dict_outline(d, indent=0):
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(' ' * indent + str(key))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_dict_outline(value, indent+2)
        elif isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(i, dict) for i in value):
            if len(value) > 0:
                keys = list(value[0].keys())
                print(' ' * (indent+2) + 'dict_list')
                for k in keys:
                    print(' ' * (indent+4) + str(k))
```

```
# Example dictionary with a list of dictionaries
my_dict = {
    'a': {
        'b': [
            {'c': 1, 'd': 2},
            {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
        ],
        'e': {
            'f': 5
        }
    },
    'g': 6
}

# Print the outline of the dictionary
print_dict_outline(my_dict)
```

The output is:

```
a
  b
    dict_list
      c
      d
  e
    f
g
```

In this implementation, if the value of a dictionary key is a list of dictionaries, we first check if the list has any elements. If it does, we define the keys of the first dictionary in the list, and print them as subheadings of 'dict_list'. We do not print the values for each dictionary in the list, only the keys. This allows us to print an outline of the nested dictionary that includes subheadings for each list of dictionaries, without printing the individual values of each dictionary.