# why Output terminal format problem shows n?

Tags: python, terminal, format, output

im having a problem with the terminal output when im running a python program... so i have this output but i want a normal json format, with tabs and new lines... can anyone help me? i already change the files.eol from vscode and nothing

> b'{\n  "args": {\n    "curso": "python", \n    "nivel": "intermedio", \n    "nombre": "Sergio"\n  }, \n  "data": "", \n  "files": {}, \n  "form": {}, \n  "headers": {\n    "Accept": "*/*", \n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", \n    "Content-Length": "0", \n    "Host": "httpbin.org", \n    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.28.1", \n    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-62ca8668-4420ad564065b8bd033ef470"\n  }, \n  "json": null, \n  "origin": "77.231.206.83", \n  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?nombre=Sergio&curso=python&nivel=intermedio"\n}\n'

Comment: This is duplicate question. You can look into this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179763/replace-b-in-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179763/replace-b-in-json)      Please do some research while posting questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pretty-print json in python (pythonic way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718896/pretty-print-json-in-python-pythonic-way)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace \b in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179763/replace-b-in-json)